# getMapAsync() - call once and save the result, or call every time I need the map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-maps-v2

Google Play Services 6.5 added the [`getMapAsync`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) method, which allows us to asynchronously retrieve the `GoogleMap` object that backs a `MapFragment` (or `MapView`). The documentation states that

> The GoogleMap object provided by the callback is non-null.

I don't have a great understanding of why asynchronous retrieval is required here (i.e., what circumstances could cause the deprecated `getMap` method to return `null`), which has led me to the following question:

When working with a `MapFragment`, should I call `getMapAsync` once in `onCreate`, store the (non-null) `GoogleMap` returned by the callback, and then reference this stored result everywhere else in my class? **Or**, should I call `getMapAsync` every time I need to interact with the `GoogleMap` object, and do *all* map-related work inside the corresponding callbacks?

The first option leads to more compact code, so I'd prefer to use it if possible. Is there any risk that the `GoogleMap` object I store could become 'stale' or `null` (in which case the second option would be safer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's map-related examples, located in the directory

```
<path-to-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps
```

keep a reference, so I believe this should be fine.

The reason you have to use the async call is (I suppose), because the map probably does network requests while it's initializing (to download the tiles etc, see the docs for more info). If this is the case, the map needs to be (partially) initialized on a separate thread. Therefore you will have to wait until the initialization is finished before you can get the `GoogleMap`.

The `getMap()` function *can* return the `GoogleMap` correctly, but it's not guaranteed. If you call the `getMap()` function too soon, the map won't be initialized yet and it will return null.

Comment: Thanks, referencing the samples was a great idea! In particular, `CameraDemoActivity` is an example `Activity` that stores a reference to the `GoogleMap` object after asynchronous retrieval. Just wanted to add that in a comment to help others find a concrete example right away.

Comment: I can confirm that the old getMap() function sometimes return null even when there is a network connection. This occurrence is rare but it happens. The new getMapAsync() and OnMapReady() functions guarantee the GoogleMap is non-null.